# Finding the expected value of this dice problem

Tags: probability, dice

> Three fair twenty-sided dice are rolled, and then arranged in decreasing order. The expected value of the largest die can be written in the form $p/q$ where $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime positive integers. Find $p+q$.

I try to find the exoected value and got $31.5$ and representing that as $p/q$, I got $63/2$ so $p + q = 65$. But the quiz master said The answer is $4$ digit. Am I missing something from the $q$ or have a wrong approach?

Comment: The max of a twenty-sided dice is 20. How can the expected value be 31.5?

Comment: Oh so 10.5? But how is the answer 4 digit?

Comment: This is the expected value of one dice, not of the maximum of 3 dices.

Comment: If 3 dices, it's 31.5

Comment: You are thinking of the sum of the three. Not the max of the three. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The probability that the maximum of three fair dices is $k$ is $\tfrac{k^3-(k-1)^3}{20^3}$ for each $k\in \{1,\ldots,20\}$ (each dice should show at most $k$, but not all of them show at most $k-1$.)

Thus, the maximum is expected to be $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{20} k\tfrac{k^3-(k-1)^3}{20^3}=\tfrac{1239}{80}$.

Comment: Is there a general formula for this question?

Comment: For the probability yes (replace 3 and 20 with the desired numbers, given the dice are $1,2,\ldots,M$). For the expectation, I'm not sure as you need the formula of the sum of the first $M$ numbers in the $L$th power ($L$ - number of dices) and I don't if there is a generalized formula.

Comment: The singular is die and the plural is dice

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use the theorem that for a random variable $X$ that takes on only non-negative values,
$$E(X) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(X>n)$$
If $X$ is the maximum of the three dice, then
$$P(X>n) = 1 - P(X \le n) = 1 - (n/20)^3$$
for $0 \le n \le 20$.
So by the theorem,
$$\begin{align}
E(X) &= \sum_{n=0}^{20} ( 1 - (n/20)^3 ) \\
&= 21 - (1/20)^3 \sum_{n=0}^{20} n^3 \\
&= 21 - (1/20)^3 \cdot (1/4) \cdot20^2 \cdot 21^2 \\
&= \frac{1239}{80}
\end{align}$$
where we used the formula for the sum of the first $n$ cubes to simplify computation.

Comment: Cool. It is interesting to note that this approach requires less numerical computation, which might be helpful in a contest.